# Pls validate my apporach on Redis, Socke.io in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, redis, socket.io

I am new to node.js so need your help in validating the below mentioned approach.

Problem: I am developing a node.js application which is broadcasts messages to the people who are specifically subscribed to a topic. If the user in logged into the application either via web or mobile I want to use socket.io to push new messages as and when they are created. As I mentioned I need to push the messages to a selected list of logged in users based on certain filters, the message is not pushed to everyone logged in only to the users matching filter criteria. This is express application.

Approach: As soon as a client makes a connection to server a socket is established. The socket will be allocated a room. The key will be login name, so if there are further request from the same login ex. multiple browser windows those sockets also will be added to the same room. The Login Name and the room with sockets will be stored in Redis. When a new message is created internal application logic will determine the users who needs to be notified. Fetch only those logins from Redis along with the room information and push the message to them. When the sockets are closed remove the Redis entry for that login...Also this needs to be scalable since i might use node cluster in the future.

I read lot of about socket.io and Redis pub/sub approach and i am not using them in the approach above. Just storing the login and sockets as key value pairs

Can you please let me know if this is a good approach. Will there be any performance/scalability issue? Is there any other better ways to do this?

Thanks a lot for all your help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're Redis model will have to be a little more complicated than that. You'll need to maintain an index using sets, so you can find intersects which can be used to find all users in a given room. You'll then need to use redis's pub/sub functionality to enable realtime notifications. You'll also need to store messages in indexed sets, then just publish to inform your application that a change has been made, therefore sending the new data from the set.

If you could provide an example I can provide some redis commands to better explain how Redis works.

## Update

This is in response to comments below.

Technologies I would use:

- [Nginx](http://nginx.org/)
- [Socket.io](http://socket.io/)
- [mranney/node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)
- [Redis](http://redis.io)

### Scaling Redis

There are several solutions to scale Redis. If you need higher concurrency you can scale using master-slave replication. If you need more memory you can set up partitioning, or you can use the Redis Cluster beta(3.0.0). Alternatively you can outsource your solution to one of many Redis services(RedisGreen,RedisLabs,etc.), however this is best paired with a PaaS provider(AWS, Google Compute, Joyent) so it can be depolyed in the same cloud.

### Scaling Socket.io

Socket.io can be [scaled using Nginx](http://tikalk.com/js/setting-nginx-server-load-balance-several-socketio-processes). This is pretty common practice when scaling WebSockets. You then can synchronize each node app(with socket.io) using Redis as a messaging protocol(pub/sub).

You can `SUBSCRIBE connections` to track when a user joins or leaves, on the event of that, which ever app/server fires the event will `PUBLISH connections update` or `PUBLISH connections "user:john left"`. If a user were to leave like in the latter example, you must also remember to remove that user from the set that represents a room(ex generalChat) so something like this `SREM generalChat user:john`, then execute the latter upon callback from the `SREM` command. Once the `PUBLISH` is sent, all apps/servers connected to redis, already having subscribed, will receive a message query from Redis in realtime notifying them to update. All apps/servers will broadcast to the corresponding room either a new user list(redis `set` type) or a command notifying the frontend to remove the user.

Basically all your sockets are in sync with Redis, so you can host multiple socket.io servers and use Messaging via Pub/Sub to queue actions across your entire cloud.

### Examples

It's not hard to scale socket.io with Redis, however Redis may be cumbersome to setup and scale, but Redis doesn't use that much memory because you manage your own relations so you therefore only have relations mapped for your specific intentions. Also you can lease cloud hosting for 8GB for $80 a month, and that would support higher concurrency than the *Big Boy* plan from pusher, for less than half the price, and you get persistence as well so your stack is more uniform and has less dependencies.

If you were to use Pusher you'd probably need a persistent storage medium like MongoDB, MySQL, Postgre, etc. With Redis you can rely on it for all your data storage(excluding file storage). This would then create more traffic depending on your implementation.

**Ex 1**
You can use pusher to notify changes and refer to the backend to populate the new/changed data.
Pusher for Messaging

```
Boiler Plate:
Client      <==    Socket Opened    ==> Pusher

Client      ===    User Left        ==> Pusher
All Clients <==    User left        === Pusher
All Clients ===    Request New Data ==> Backend <==> Database
All Clients <==    Response         === Backend
```

This can create a lot of problems, and you'd have to implement timeouts. This also takes a lot of Pusher connections, which is expensive.

**Ex 2**
You can connect to pusher with your backend to save the frontend from handling many requests(probably better for mobile users). This saves pusher traffic, because its not sending to hundreds/thousands of clients, just a handful of your backend servers.

This example assumes that you have 4 socket.io servers running.
Pusher for MQ on Backend

```
Boiler Plate:
Backend 1/2/3/4   <==    Socket Opened          ==> Pusher

Backend 1         ===    Remove User from room  ==> Database
Backend 1         ===    User Leaves            ==> Pusher
Backend 1/2/3/4   <==    Use Left               === Pusher
Backend 1/2/3/4   ===    Get Data               ==> Database
Backend 1/2/3/4   <==    Recieve Data           === Database 
Backend 1/2/3/4   ===    New Data               ==> Room(clients)
```

**Ex 3**
You can use Redis as explained above.

Again assuming 4 socket.io servers.
Redis as MQ and datastore

```
Boiler Plate:
Backend 1/2/3/4  <==    Connected                    ==>  Redis
Backend 1/2/3/4  ===    Subscribe                    ==>  Redis

Backend 1        ===    User Left                    ==>  Redis (removes user)
Backend 1        ===    PUBLISH queue that user left ==>  Redis
Backend 1/2/3/4  <==    User Left Message            ===  Redis
Backend 1/2/3/4  ===    Get New Data                 ==>  Redis
Backend 1/2/3/4  <==    New Data                     ===  Redis
Backend 1/2/3/4  ===    New Data                     ==>  Room(clients)
```

All of these examples can be improved and optimized significantly, but I won't do that for sake of readability and clarity.

### Conclusion

If you know how Redis works implementing this should be fairly straight forward. If you're learning redis you should start out a little smaller to get a hang of how redis works(its more than key:value storage). In the end running redis would be more cost effective, and efficient, but would take longer to develop. Pusher would be much more expensive, include more dependencies into your stack, and wouldn't be as effective(pusher is on a different cloud). Only advantage for using Pusher or any other service similar to it, is the ease of use for the platform they provide. You're essentially paying a monthly fee for boilerplate code and stack management.

#### Bottom Line

It would be best to reverse proxy with Nginx regardless of which stack you choose, so you can easily scale.

Redis, Socket.io, Node.js stack would be the best for large scale projects, and professional products. It will keep your operating cost down, and increase your concurrency without dramatically increasing your cost as you scale.

Redis, Socket.io(optional), Node.js, Pusher, Database stack would be best for smaller projects that you don't expect much growth out of. Once you get to 5,000 connections you're forking out $199/mo just for pusher, then you have to consider the cost for the rest of your stack. If you connect your backend to Pusher instead you'll save money, increase production time, and you'll still suffer performance hits from retrieving data from a thirdparty cloud.

Comment: Thanks tsturzl, so you think socket.io and redis is a scaleable model? I don't know much about redis and wanted opinions around using it for my use case as i need spend time to learn and code it correctly...

Comment: Thanks tsturzl, i will go through your approach on spending time understand how Redis work and take it from there....

Comment: It's difficult to understand at first. Some redis operations remind me of Matrix math. If you need help to understand, feel free to message me.